# Como adicionar mais de um DataRelation à um Dataset no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

É possível adicionar mais de uma DataRelation a um DataSet? Preciso que três colunas em tabelas distintas sejam relacionadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi assim:

```
DataTable parentDtbl = new DataTable();
DataTable childDtbl = new DataTable();    

parentDtbl = RetornarData1();
childDtbl = RetornarData2();

DataSet dtSet = new DataSet();
dtSet.Tables.AddRange(new DataTable[] { parentDtbl, childDtbl });

DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("relation",
                        new DataColumn[] { dtSet.Tables[0].Columns[0], dtSet.Tables[0].Columns[1], dtSet.Tables[0].Columns[2] },
                        new DataColumn[] { dtSet.Tables[1].Columns[0], dtSet.Tables[1].Columns[1], dtSet.Tables[1].Columns[2]}, false);

dtSet.Relations.Add(relation);
```